# I cannot seem to install wubi on windows 8.1 Pro (Surface Pro 2)

Tags: installation, wubi, windows-8, surface

I just bought Surface Pro 2 (with Windows 8.1 Pro) from the store yesterday and tried installing wubi (right before them) and ran into some boot up issues. Luckily I was able to enter Windows again and uninstall it. Anyone who can help me with this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Answer (score 1):

Wubi does not work with computers pre-installed with Windows 8 and higher. There is no way around it. Your only choice is to do a full install.

See [Installing Ubuntu on a pre-installed Windows 8 64 bit system (UEFI supported)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported) for details on how to do it.